# How effective is Genetic Algorithm for finding Attribute-Value relationships

Tags: data-mining, genetic-algorithms

I am implementing a module which finds based on user interactions on an online portal to find which attributes of a certain product and what values for those products influence the buyer to choose the said Item.

My employers have suggested me to use Genetic Algorithm to achieve this. I have started implementing and found even the initial population generation to be a bit ineffective. Before I go further with this I would like your thoughts whether 'Genetic Algorithm' is the right way or is there a better way to go about this.

For me each genome is a list of attributes and their corresponding values.

Eg. genome 1: Color: Black, Material: wool, thread count:5
     genome 2: Color: white, Handwash: yes, Dry clean only: No

Its a mixture of different attributes and their values. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Are you working from a history of sales for the customers? Or are you using the genetic algorithm to choose "live" what to present to customers and seeing what works best at the end of a real sales day? Do you have *any* customer attributes to use to personalise the suggestions, or are you treating all customers the same (just with random variations)?

Comment: Currently im using history data. though the intent is to find patterns which can be used to improve real time user experiences

Comment: The plan outlined in the question seems quite vague, so it is difficult to assess it. For instance you say "based on user interactions", then give an example genome which does not use any interaction data, it is just a product description. It is perfectly valid to present recommendations/adverts based purely on product description (and measure user interactions in bulk results, not per user), but that doesn't appear to be your goal. I think you need to give more details about your goal, and be more precise in the problem description, before anyone could help you.

Comment: you are right. first I would like to know what attributes and what value for those attributes for a product or a set product, compels a user to purchase an item. (disregarding demographic, social or seasonal influences for now)

Comment: I still think you need to explain more in your question. Use the [edit] link to give more details. Add some concrete goals and your plans to achieve them, give one or two examples of the user interaction data you have (simplified, and with anything identifying removed) - for instance is the interaction data what the user has looked at, whether they have clicked an existing advert, what they bought in the past?

Comment: I'm not sure what the GA is intended to do here. For a GA to work, you basically need two things: the ability to generate and manipulate individuals via genetic operators like crossover and mutation, and the ability to provide a numeric value for each individual that you intend to minimize or maximize (called a fitness function). What's the fitness function here?

I think you're probably better off looking at what was classically called "data mining" approaches, but without fully understanding the goal here, that's a bit of a guess.